# Bring back default amsmath symbols

Tags: fonts, symbols, mathabx

I looked up the tutorial on how to [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) but it's still not clear for me to make changes myself.

In my case I'd like to use `mathabx` as my main font, but import the default `\in`, `\subset`, `\supset`, `\cap`, `\cup`, `\land`, `\lor`, `\Leftarrow`, `\Rightarrow`, `\Leftrightarrow`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just look in `fontmath.ltx`, where the standard definitions are made.

Since `mathabx` doesn't override the standard symbol fonts, they are still available. Just copy the relevant lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\in}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\subset}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\supset}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cup}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cap}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\wedge}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vee}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\land}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lor}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"5F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Leftarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Rightarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Leftrightarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"2C}

\begin{document}

$\in\subset\supset\cup\cap\land\lor\Leftarrow\Rightarrow\Leftrightarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following would be the output with just `mathabx`.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of importing the symbols from Computer Modern after loading `mathabx`, you can use `\let` to define aliases to the corresponding commands before to load the package. This way, you will still be able to use the symbols from Computer Modern with these aliases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\cmin\in
\let\cmsubset\subset
\let\cmsupset\supset
\let\cmcap\cap
\let\cmcup\cup
\let\cmland\land
\let\cmlor\lor
\let\cmLeftarrow\Leftarrow
\let\cmRightarrow\Rightarrow
\let\cmLeftrightarrow\Leftrightarrow
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\( \in\subset\supset\cap\cup\land\lor\Leftarrow\Rightarrow\Leftrightarrow \)

\( \cmin\cmsubset\cmsupset\cmcap\cmcup\cmland\cmlor\cmLeftarrow\cmRightarrow\cmLeftrightarrow \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want, you can of course renew all of these commands so that the usual commands refer to the symbols from Computer Modern rather than those of `mathabx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\cmin\in
\let\cmsubset\subset
\let\cmsupset\supset
\let\cmcap\cap
\let\cmcup\cup
\let\cmland\land
\let\cmlor\lor
\let\cmLeftarrow\Leftarrow
\let\cmRightarrow\Rightarrow
\let\cmLeftrightarrow\Leftrightarrow
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\in\cmin
\let\subset\cmsubset
\let\supset\cmsupset
\let\cap\cmcap
\let\cup\cmcup
\let\land\cmland
\let\lor\cmlor
\let\Leftarrow\cmLeftarrow
\let\Rightarrow\cmRightarrow
\let\Leftrightarrow\cmLeftrightarrow
\begin{document}
\( \in\subset\supset\cap\cup\land\lor\Leftarrow\Rightarrow\Leftrightarrow \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I'd like to use default aliases, without that "cm" prefix.

Comment: @antshar It is indeed possible, as I remarked in the comment at the end of my answer. I'll edit it to make it more explicit.

Comment: I like this answer as it allows you to do (almost) the same but without the need of looking up the symbol identifier!